XCP-NG VM won't boot. fsck error writing file system info input/output error
I recently had a VM that wouldn't boot.  It's a Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine. On another ubuntu machine setup the same way, I ran fdisk -l to see what partitions were listed.  xvda1 is listed as 1M BIOS boot, xvda2 is listed as the Linux Filesystem.
My first step was to boot into linux desktop and run fsck /dev/xvda2. xvda At the end the response was

error writing file system info input/output error

I did some googling and tried a few things but all of the responses to that error seemed to be aimed a physical disk without any luck.

so what things did you try? And have you checked with your virtualizer that there's free space for your drive data?

I ran across a post about testdisk, but I couldn't get it to install on the live desktop iso I was running on that instance.  I also ran mdadm and it returned an error "no superblock detected on /dev/xvda2".

why would you use mdadm on something that you fsck'ed? These are two different tools for different kinds of volumes. Maybe you want to start by editing the question with information on what is supposed to be on volume /dev/xvda2?

@MarcusMüller I added a little more information above

As it turns out the primary storage was completely full.  I assume that's why fsck returned the IO error.  As soon as I was able to get the VM some space everything worked fine.
